# How to debug Jest tests in the browser?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

How do you guys proceed when having to debug Jest tests? I remember back in the days, when I was using Mocha, I could use a headless browser to do CLI testing but there was also the possibility of loading the tests into a browser and use more powerful debugging capabilities like Chrome Dev Tools. For example, `console.log` with Jest just plainly sucks.

I tried to use https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting and use Node Debugger but its behavior is erratic (it doesn't always connect to the debugger or stops at the right place) and `console.log` is not output to the console.

Is there a way I'm not aware of of having the same functionality in Jest?

Comment: have you tried to attach Chrome developer tools to the process as it's described?

Comment: @skyboyer can you explain how to attach?

Comment: @SamKahChiin link above describes that, if you face any issues it'd be better to start separate thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, I am using Visual Studio Code.
Through a "launch.json" file I start jest, and this way you can debug directly in your IDE.